# How to use ajax Nobot control in Asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net

I have no idea how to use Ajax Nobot control in Asp.net MVC.Please help me.

Regards,
Tejveer

Answer (score 1):

That is part of the AJAX control toolkit, although I believe you can [get it to work](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2008/08/25/using-the-ajax-control-toolkit-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx) with MVC I do not think it is the most elegant solution. I would recommend using an alternate CAPTCHA. I highly recommend [ReCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha).

Comment: But client has specifically asked to use Ajax Nobot control.That is why I raised this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at this tutorial:
http://v4.ajaxtutorials.com/tutorials/asp-net/ajax-control-toolkit-nobot-extender-tutorial-in-asp-net-c-2/

I suppose is for Asp.Net Web Forms but could be used in MVC. Hope can helps.